# Pass ID variable into a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have the following link which opens a jquery modal window:

```
<div id='confirm-dialog'><a href='#' class='confirm'><img src='1.png' /></a></div>
```

and the following JS code which processes it:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#confirm-dialog input.confirm, #confirm-dialog a.confirm').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item id='IDNUMBER'.", function () {
            window.location.href = 'path to php process script';
        });
    });
});

function confirm(message, callback) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
        position: ["30%",],
        overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
        containerId: 'confirm-container', 
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            var modal = this;

            $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

            // if the user clicks "yes"
            $('.yes', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
                // call the callback
                if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback.apply();
                }
                // close the dialog
                modal.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I am unable to solve two issues:

1. How do I pass the ID variable (perhaps other variables) into the javascript function so that when I submit 'yes' on the confirmation window, the php path will include something like : http://www.pathtophp.com?ID=12345
2. How do I display the ID variable within the popup text (shown as: ...delete item id="IDNUMBER"...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply in the head of the page the PHP generates (before including the other JS files) add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Assumes id is passed in the URL
var id = <?php print $_GET['id'];?>;
</script>
```

Then the variable "id" is available to all JavaScript functions on the page.

Alternatively, if there are multiple links on the page you are wanting to apply this functionality to, you could add the id to the rel attribute of the anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="confirm" rel="<?php print $id;?>">
```

Then you'll modify your jQuery function to

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#confirm-dialog input.confirm, #confirm-dialog a.confirm').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item id='"+ e.currentTarget.rel +"'.", function () {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.pathtophp.com?ID=' + e.currentTarget.rel;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Daniel - not sure where you were going with the first part necessarilty but the 2nd is actually what I was trying to accomplish. The action could take place on approximately 100 items (e.g. 100 ids) on the same page. I have tested and can confirm your suggestion works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: on a side note- is there any real benefit to using "javascript:void(0)" over simply using href="#"? - Also, do you have any documentation on the 'rel' path and how it is used regarding JS - this seems to be very helpful.

Comment: @Daniel - also looking back, is there a way to pass 'multiple' variables into the rel tag? For example - i need to pass the ID for the url purposes but i need to pass a name as well so: "Are you sure you want to delete: John Doe?" then have a yes go to "http://www.deleteuser.com?ID=12345"

Comment: I think its more of a personal preference; I could probably give reasons for and against both. I personally choose 'javascript:void(0)' because I believe Firefox throws warnings about '#' being invalid. As far as the rel attribute, from w3schools: "The rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document" (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp). The attribute doesn't do anything in the browser, its just a good way to store data with an element on the page and still validate.

Comment: You could separate multiple values in the rel tag with a semi-colon and then using str.split(';') to separate the arguments.

Comment: Or you could create an associative array at the top of the page and associate each id with a name.

Answer (score 0):

for 1 you can use like below

`var value= "<%=value from server side%`>"

Comment: @once you have value in javascript which is value here , you can display in any fashion.

Comment: @alexy , you vote down , thats a generic answer based on the syntax it can be used in any language

Comment: generic in the sense , atleast it gives a direction to the person and solution is almost right apart from syntax

Comment: I voted up due to it being a valid answer, however not as helpful as it could be.